# "A intersects B at C" or "A and B intersect at C"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, mathematics

Two expressions for using the word "intersect":

"A intersects B at C" OR

"A and B intersect at C",

Which one is more natural?

Comment: I liked this question!  Not sure why there has been a downvote, it seems a valid question and is clearly asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think both are correct and would be clearly understood.

'A Intersects B at' seems more natural to me, a British English speaker. I think this is because the second version has an implied object in the phrase (A and B intersect 'each other' at C).

Comment: As an Am.E. speaker, I find the second one more natural!

Comment: So both expressions have the same meaning?

Comment: Cautiously I would say yes.  In terms of the English (this is an English question) they are both understood clearly and would both be perceived as **conveying the same information**.  The reason for the caution is that normally intersects is used in a mathematical context.  I can't think of any situations where we might have A Intersecting B at C, but A and B don't intersect at C but I think there *could* be branches of mathematics or data science using the term intersect where that might be true.